# How to get back all my changes in git?

Tags: git

Today while I was working on a project, I came to a point where I "broke" my code and nothing was working correctly. I used "git checkout" to go to a previous commit where everything was still working, and decided to finish the project from there. After committing and pushing my changes for some time, I checked back into the master or HEAD branch. The problem is, all my changes that I made before checking back into master/HEAD branch are gone. My git log does not even show any of the commits I made after checking back in.

Is there a way to get back any of my code before I checked back into the master/HEAD branch?

Comment: What does the output of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` look like?  If you committed and pushed your changes, chances are they're on a separate branch to master.

Comment: Run `git reflog`.

Comment: If the previous commit you checked out wasn't itself a branch head, you didn't have a pointer to where the new commits were going.